# Excel 2010 VBA - Trying to retrieve data from site using API JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

Thank you in advance for any help!!  First time using api calls.  Trying to input an ISBN into a cell the retrieving information from my inventory file located at artofbooks.com Their documentation for their API calls is not that great.  This is my code and I am getting a "bad token" error.

```
 sub test
    creds = EncodeBase64("{ AOB_AUTH_USER : cottagebooks, AOB_AUTH_PW : xxxxxx }")
    isbn = Cells(5, 3).Value
   
    
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    URL = "https://www.theartofbooks.com/api/2.0/item=2010101257"
    objHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization:", "Bearer " & creds
    
    objHttp.Send
    strResponseStatus = objHttp.Status
    strresponsetext = objHttp.ResponseText
    strresponsetext = CStr(strresponsetext)
         
   MsgBox strresponsetext
end sub
```

Comment: I would guess that your `item=2010101257` has an incorrect inventory number. Can you type in the URL manually into your browser (or copy/paste) and does it work after you log in?

Comment: Yes if i type it in a browser it works fine. I am also logged into artofbooks in another browser at the time. I think that is my problem. The authentication part

Comment: Try adding AOB_AUTH_USER and AOB_AUTH_PW just as regular (non-encoded) headers.  The docs don't seem to indicate you can use Base-64 encoded parameters in headers, only as inputs in the URL...

Comment: here is a link to the authentication documentation part. I appreciate any help!  Thanks!! https://zoobilee.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041894371-Overview

Comment: @TimWilliams - Do you have an example on how I would do this?

Comment: If I copy that string im sending to encodedbase64 and put it after Bearer, I still get bad token error

Comment: I mean like `objHttp.SetRequestHeader "AOB_AUTH_USER", "cottagebooks"` and `objHttp.SetRequestHeader "AOB_AUTH_PW", "xxxxxxx"` Also it looks like the API output is JSON, so you may want to change your "Accept" header.

Comment: Yes!! That works!  Thanks so much!!! @TimWilliams